# Javascript controls html so the external js does not see the html name field

Tags: javascript, html, anytime

I am building a form using a js+html and I ran into a problem. There's a part of my form where user should be able to click on a textfield and pick a date & time from a calendar(**anytime.js by MAM3**), and since my form(*partial code*) is built this way:

```
third_list = "<table class='table'>";
if (radio_array[genIndex] == reserve) {
    third_list += "<tr><td id='Date:'><label><span id='Date'>Date:</span><input type='text' id='Date' name='_date' size='20' onfocus='showMessage()'/></label></td>";
    third_list += "<td id='Time:'><label><span id='Time'>Time:</span><input type='text' id='Time' name='_time' size='20' /></label></td>";
    document.getElementById("third").innerHTML = third_list;
    l3_value = "";
    return;
}
```

and by putting this to the html:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    AnyTime.widget
        ( "Date",
            { format: "%m/%d/%Z" }
        );
    AnyTime.widget
        ( "Time",
            { format: "%h:%i:%p" }
        );
    </script>
```

it does not pop-up a calendar.

**Side notes:** I have included all of the required js&css files and tried to see if it works on a seperate text field out from js, and it works. I think the reason it doesnt work is it is controlled by js, so the **anytime.js** does not see it as a **html name field**.

**SN2:** onfocus='showMessage()' in my js is to show a message when a user clicks on a text field.

How do I make it work?

Comment: Ids should be unique, three elements with the same are two too much. This also might be the root cause of your problem, although I don't know how anytime.js gets the elements.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I changed all of them and made them unique ids, issue still exists. any other suggestions by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues:

First, you have more than one element with the `id` values `Date` and `Time`. `id` values **must** be unique in the document. I expect the script isn't getting the element it expects and is failing to init. The [documentation for AnyTime](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/) seems to suggest it uses the first argument you give `AnyTime.widget` as an `id` and expects to get an input field. In your case, it usually won't on most browsers, because when faced with an invalid structure featuring duplicate `id`s, most browsers will return the first one when you ask for "the" element with that `id`, which in your case is a `span` rather than an input field.

Your `Date` elements:

```
<span id='Date'>Date:</span><input type='text' id='Date' ... />
<!--      ^--- one                                 ^--- two -->
```

The `Time` is the same sort of problem.

Separately from that, I suspect you need to ensure that the elements exist when you call `AnyTime.widget`. I don't know where you have that `script` tag that calls it, but what you need to do is make this calls *after* you've executed the line

```
document.getElementById("third").innerHTML = third_list;
```

...so that the elements in question exist in the DOM. So for instance:

```
third_list = "<table class='table'>";
if (radio_array[genIndex] == reserve) {
    third_list += "<tr><td id='Date:'><label><span id='Date'>Date:</span><input type='text' id='Date' name='_date' size='20' onfocus='showMessage()'/></label></td>";
    third_list += "<td id='Time:'><label><span id='Time'>Time:</span><input type='text' id='Time' name='_time' size='20' /></label></td>";
    document.getElementById("third").innerHTML = third_list;
    l3_value = "";
    setUpWidgets();
    return;
}

// ...elsewhere in the same scope or a containing scope:
function setUpWidgets() {
    AnyTime.widget
        ( "Date",
            { format: "%m/%d/%Z" }
        );
    AnyTime.widget
        ( "Time",
            { format: "%h:%i:%p" }
        );
}
```

That creates a function, which you call when the elements are there.

---

Side note: You also have an `id` that looks like this:

```
 <td id='Date:'>
```

Although that's a [valid `id` in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute), it [wasn't valid in HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) and [isn't valid in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). So if you try to use that `id` in a CSS-style selector (for instance, with jQuery), you'll probably run into trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. However, it did not solve the issue. I have changed them to totally different identifications and still not getting it. So duplicate id could be an issue but still does not resolve my problem.

Comment: @makalele: I've updated, I think you were also calling `AnyTime.widget` too early.

Comment: I was actually calling anytime.widget before the closing tag of <form> so, </form>. I used your creating function method and also tried to put it as a onfocus='setUpWidgets()', no luck :(

Comment: I tried onfocus='setUpWidgets()' on a seperate textfield which was not in js, and it worked again. So, I believe there is an issue because of this **third_list +=** .

Comment: I am accepting your answer since it worked out! I used onfocus='setUpWidgets()' on one field, and it seemed to work for the other one automatically - magic! It was not working earlier - probably cached pages. Thank you very much!

Comment: Date and time fields appear after user chose any given radio button. After the first one, if a user changes his mind to choose a different radio button where new date and time fields appear, anytime widget will not appear on click. Any ideas?

Comment: If you haven't solved this yet:  firstly, you're using an old version of anytime.js; you should download the latest (4.1112L) from www.ama3.com/anytime/ .  Secondly, if you're using the same ID for the new input field that you used for the old input field, you'll need to call AnyTime.noPicker() on the ID before you call AnyTime.picker() a second time.  The library keeps an internal table of IDs that have pickers on them, and refuses to create a second picker if a first picker already exists.  Your JavaScript debugger/error console should have reported this as an exception.

Comment: BTW, if you have further problems using Any+Time(TM), try using the contact page on www.ama3.com as I will usually respond rather quickly.

Comment: @AndrewM.AndrewsIII: makalele won't have received notification of the comments above without an @ direction. (I did because I wrote the answer.)

Comment: @makalele: See Andrew's comments above.

Comment: Thanks Andrew and Crowder, I have solved the problem with both of your helps! Special thanks to AMA.